# Update existing value with sum of itself and another column

Tags: oracle, sum

In Oracle, i'm trying to update a value with the sum of itself and 1 value from another schema/table. Below is what i have tried so far to no avail.

```
UPDATE DEV02I2B2DEMODATA.partition_obs_2
SET COUNT = SUM(COUNT+CPT_COUNT)
WHERE prefix IN (SELECT concept_cd FROM 
PCORI_ETL_WEIGHT2.CONCEPT_COUNT_OBS_FACT_17Q1);

UPDATE 
(SELECT * FROM t1.partition_obs_2 D
JOIN t2.CONCEPT_COUNT_OBS_FACT_17Q1 P ON D.PREFIX = P.CONCEPT_CD
) D
SET D.COUNT = SUM(D.COUNT+P.CPT_COUNT)
```

Each time i am getting error 'ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here' which im not sure how to proceed with

Both tables contain 2 columns

```
CREATE TABLE "DEV02I2B2DEMODATA"."PARTITION_OBS_2" 
(   "PREFIX" VARCHAR2(500 BYTE), 
"COUNT" NUMBER)

CREATE TABLE "PCORI_ETL_WEIGHT2"."CONCEPT_COUNT_OBS_FACT_17Q1" 
(   "CPT_COUNT" NUMBER, 
"CONCEPT_CD" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE))
```

Some sample data, both tables looks like this apart from the header.

```
PREFIX  COUNT
CPT:000 2077
CPT:001 90169
CPT:002 2626
```

I'm trying to sum together the count column from both tables for each prefix and update the count column in DEV02I2B2DEMODATA.PARTITION_OBS_2

Any advise would be appreciated

Thanks,
Allan

Comment: You want to add the current row value in one table, to the sum of values from the other table? Correlated on `prefix` and `concept_cd`? Including the table DDL, sample data in both tables and expected final result would be helpful.

Comment: Apologies, just added further information to the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want a correlated update with a subquery to get the sum from another table:

```
UPDATE DEV02I2B2DEMODATA.partition_obs_2 po
SET COUNT = COUNT + (
  SELECT NVL(SUM(CPT_COUNT), 0)
  FROM PCORI_ETL_WEIGHT2.CONCEPT_COUNT_OBS_FACT_17Q1 ccof
  WHERE ccof.CONCEPT_ID = po.PREFIX
);
```

Or skip the `NVL()` but add an `EXISTS` clause to limit the update to rows which have matching data in the other table; if that's a low proportion then doing that check would probably be better than updating every row.

Quick demo with your table structures and some made-up sample data (all in one schema for simplicity):

```
CREATE TABLE "PARTITION_OBS_2" 
(   "PREFIX" VARCHAR2(500 BYTE), 
"COUNT" NUMBER)
/

CREATE TABLE "CONCEPT_COUNT_OBS_FACT_17Q1" 
(   "CPT_COUNT" NUMBER, 
"CONCEPT_CD" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE))
/

insert into PARTITION_OBS_2 values ('CPT:000', 2077);
insert into PARTITION_OBS_2 values ('CPT:001', 90169);
insert into PARTITION_OBS_2 values ('CPT:002', 2626);

insert into CONCEPT_COUNT_OBS_FACT_17Q1 values (1, 'CPT:001');
insert into CONCEPT_COUNT_OBS_FACT_17Q1 values (1, 'CPT:001');
insert into CONCEPT_COUNT_OBS_FACT_17Q1 values (1, 'CPT:001');
insert into CONCEPT_COUNT_OBS_FACT_17Q1 values (2, 'CPT:002');
insert into CONCEPT_COUNT_OBS_FACT_17Q1 values (5, 'CPT:002');

UPDATE partition_obs_2 po
SET COUNT = COUNT + (
  SELECT NVL(SUM(CPT_COUNT), 0)
  FROM CONCEPT_COUNT_OBS_FACT_17Q1 ccof
  WHERE ccof.CONCEPT_CD = po.PREFIX
);

3 rows updated.

column prefix format a20
select * from partition_obs_2;

PREFIX                    COUNT
-------------------- ----------
CPT:000                    2077
CPT:001                   90172
CPT:002                    2633
```

Answer (score 0):

Just turn the SET part into a subquery.

```
UPDATE t1.partition_obs_2 A
SET A.COUNT = (SELECT SUM(D.COUNT+P.CPT_COUNT) FROM t1.partition_obs_2 D
JOIN t2.CONCEPT_COUNT_OBS_FACT_17Q1 P ON D.PREFIX = P.CONCEPT_CD)
WHERE prefix IN (SELECT concept_cd FROM 
PCORI_ETL_WEIGHT2.CONCEPT_COUNT_OBS_FACT_17Q1);
```